# Show and hide p:blockUI in managed bean

Tags: jsf, primefaces, managed-bean, blockui

I have a page with 2 dropdowns (We'll call then drop 1 and drop 2). When the user selects something from drop 1 I have a method that is called and runs a query that will populate drop 2 based on what drop 1 is. What I need to do is block the UI when drop 1 is changed and then unblock it when the query has returned and populated drop 2. I have a stub of how I think it should work but not sure how to access block UI from code.

```
public void onPrimaryQueryDataSourceChanged() {
    // ** Block UI **
    try {
        // Run query, get results, and populate dropdown
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    } finally {
        // ** Unblock UI **
    }
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: two upvotes in 10 minutes? And you cannot do what you want. At least not in a simple way. The possible option is so complex that I'd advise against it and use the `p:ajax` on start and oncomplete from javascript

Comment: Ok, if this is not possible; how about just disabling the dropdown with the call to the database is made to get the data that will be used to populate it.    There has to be some type of solution to my problem. I am not opposed to adding JavaScript, I just don't know how because I am still learning JSF and PrimeFaces.

Comment: you don't need javascript. Read my comment carefully and look at the showcase

Answer (score 0):

### Concept

- You can't show blockUI in java code.
- You can show blockUI in JS script.
- You can specify JS script in java code to run after response completes.

To specify JS script in java code to run after response completes PrimeFaces offers RequestContext utility with function `execute(String script)` - executes script after ajax request completes or on page load.

### Problem with supposed stub

Lets look at your stub:

```
public void onPrimaryQueryDataSourceChanged() {
// ** Block UI **
// To show blockUI you may write the following: 
   RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("PF('myBlockUI').show();");
// Note that even it is called "execute"
// script "PF('myBlockUI').show();" will be executed AFTER RESPONSE COMPLETE.
// So here you need to return. 
// Then the response with included JS script to show blockUI will be send.
// Then client retrieves the response and runs your JS script.
// Then JS script shows blockUI. 
// So the remaining code below is misplaced.
try {
    // Run query, get results, and populate dropdown
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();

} finally {
    // ** Unblock UI **
}
```

### Solution

Ajax has basic technique for your case. You may use:

- onstart // here you show blockUI
- action itself(ajax request) // here at server side you populate values for dropdown
- oncomplete // here you hide blockUI

#### Concrete solution

Just mix examples from PrimeFaces Showcase:
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/dropdown.xhtml
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/blockUI.xhtml

So you may write the following:

```
<h:panelGrid id="panelGridId" columns="2" cellpadding="5">
        <p:outputLabel for="country" value="Country: " />
        <p:selectOneMenu id="country" value="#{dropdownView.country}">
            <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{dropdownView.onCountryChange}"
                update="city" onstart="PF('myBlockUI').show()"
                oncomplete="PF('myBlockUI').hide()" />
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select Country" itemValue=""
                noSelectionOption="true" />
            <f:selectItems value="#{dropdownView.countries}" />
        </p:selectOneMenu>

        <p:outputLabel for="city" value="City: " />
        <p:selectOneMenu id="city" value="#{dropdownView.city}">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select City" itemValue=""
                noSelectionOption="true" />
            <f:selectItems value="#{dropdownView.cities}" />
        </p:selectOneMenu>

        <p:blockUI block="panelGridId" widgetVar="myBlockUI" />
    </h:panelGrid>
```

where `onCountryChange` - function where you populate `cities` for city dropdown.

Such behavior is a common case so PrimeFaces offers declarative way of showing blockUI with encapsulated onstart and oncomplete scipts:

`<p:blockUI block="panelGridId" trigger="country" />`

where `trigger` is a list of component's ids which ajax requests trigger the blockUI to be shown.